# How to fix "django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [“'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.”]"

Tags: python, django, django-models

#models.py

```
class Questions:
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    slug = `models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default="question")`

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

#views.py

```
def import_sheet(request):

        if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,
                              request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.FILES['file'].save_to_database(
                name_columns_by_row=2,
                model=Question,
                mapdict=['question_text', 'pub_date', 'slug'])
            return HttpResponse("OK")
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'perfimport/import.html', {'form': form})
```

Terminal output

```
Internal Server Error: /import/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", l
ine 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 1
15, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 1
13, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\PerfImport\importer\perfimport\views.py", line 20, in import_sheet
    mapdict=['question_text', 'pub_date', 'slug'])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django_excel\__init__.py", line
 49, in save_to_database
    pe.save_as(**params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\core.py", line 82, in s
ave_as
    return sources.save_sheet(sheet, **dest_keywords)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line
 48, in save_sheet
    return _save_any(a_source, sheet)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line
 60, in _save_any
    a_source.write_data(instance)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\sources\db_sour
ces.py", line 65, in write_data
    **self._keywords
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\renderers\djang
o.py", line 37, in render_sheet_to_stream
    **keywords
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 129, in
 save_data
    **keywords
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 146, in
 store_data
    writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py", line 221,
in write
    sheet_writer.close()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\database\importers\d
jango.py", line 54, in close
    self.__objs, batch_size=self.__batch_size
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82
, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 474,
 in bulk_create
    ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1211
, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186
, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", li
ne 1331, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", li
ne 1275, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", li
ne 1275, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", li
ne 1274, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", li
ne 1215, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
 line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
 line 1273, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
 line 1268, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
 line 1243, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'pub_date' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD form
```

Comment: Where does this `save_to_database` on an uploaded file come from? I don’t think that’s a method in Django, something to do with pyexcel? So it’s not clear where your input comes from. Are you saving multiple rows of a csv file? If so show us the file.

Comment: I use pyexcel. It works  when i replace datefield at charfield in my models.

Comment: It would have been useful to explain this when you wrote your question. Always explain what you’re trying to do to set the right context. Anyway, how does the excel file look like. Show us a row. Looks like the date column isn’t processed properly.

Comment: question_text pub_date         slug
Java         2019-10-02 question

Comment: What you see in Excel isn't necessarily the value in the file. The only way to find out what's going on here is to use a good debugger, and set a breakpoint in django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in the function `get_db_prep_value()` for example to inspect the `value` that is being passed.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `mapdict` be dict (rather than a list)?

Answer (score 2):

Your default date cannot be an empty string. Since you allow for `NULL`, just don't set a default, that way if the date is missing, it will just be `NULL`.

So change:

```
pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
```

to:

```
pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Then show us your full error trace (edit your question) so we can see on which line of your code the error is thrown.

Comment: That’s not the full stack trace, the full trace contains usually more than 15 lines. And it shows the line on **your code** that causes the error.  And as I said, please edit your question

Comment: My answer might not solve the direct issue but it’s correct. You can’t have default=‘’, you’d get the same format error when creating rows with a blank date.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error coming from the data you are attempting to put into the database or is arising from the form you have. It seems more likely it is coming from the model validations but I'm not entirely sure without the form class.

I'm assuming this is coming from the `pub_date` field on the Question model so the data being entered isn't in the format the form/model is expecting. If you can share the actual data (or a useful example) we can help out with troubleshooting what exactly is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code for **creation of table** then it will give an Validation Error because **Date** must be in **DATE Format** not **Default=""**.
Soln. 1 => try not to mention **default=''**
Soln.2 => If you are **altering table**, if then you get an above Error then you Have to Delete your all Migration folder and run the models.py again . This One Worked For me.